# Access in-app purchase on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iOS app that includes an in-app purchase that consists of a PNG file that is downloaded to the user's device.

From what I can tell viewing log statements, the file is being dowloaded successfully to this directory:

`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ABC43D27-B79C-486C-AE39-F34BF6EF8658/Documents/`

How can I move the file to a location on the user's device where the user will be able to access the file, such as in the user's iCloud storage?

In case this would be useful, below is my code for downloading the file.

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedDownloads downloads: [SKDownload]) {
    for download:AnyObject in downloads {
        if let down:SKDownload = download as? SKDownload {
            switch down.downloadState {
            case .Active:
                NSLog("progress %f", down.progress)
                NSLog("remaining %f", down.timeRemaining)
                NSLog("Active")
                break
            case .Cancelled:
                NSLog("%@", "download cancelled")
                break
            case .Failed:
                NSLog("%@", "download failed")
                textView.text = "Download Failed"
                break
            case .Finished:
                NSLog("Finished")
                let source = down.contentURL?.relativePath
                //var dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: (source! as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("ContentInfo.plist"))
                let pathToDownloadsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
                //let pathToDownloadsFolder = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
                let content:String =
                    (pathToDownloadsFolder as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("bonus_brune_image.png")
                //let content:String = pathToDownloadsFolder.URLByAppendingPathComponent("bonus_brune_image.png")
                    self.copyPathToDownloadsFolder(source!, target: content)
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(down.transaction)
                    break
            case .Paused:
                NSLog("%@", "download paused")
                break
            case .Waiting:
                NSLog("%@", "download waiting")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func copyPathToDownloadsFolder(source:String, target:String) {
    NSLog("Source is %@", source)
    NSLog("Target is %@", target)

    let filemgr:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    do {
    try filemgr.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: target)
        NSLog("Success: file is now in %@", target)
    } catch let e as NSError {
        NSLog(String(e))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the solution is this: use **iTunes file sharing**.

To enable iTunes file sharing, set the key `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `true` in your `info.plist`.

Then when the user connects the device to iTunes and views the installed Apps in iTunes, your app will be listed in the "file sharing" apps, and the documents stored in the app's `Documents` directory will be available for the user to save.